# ISNULL(value, 0) in WHERE clause MYSQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, isnull

I have this requets:

```
SELECT sc.no, scl.quantite, scl.description, scl.poids, scl.prix, sl_ref.refsl, sl_ref.codetva, sl_ref.tauxtva, sl_ref.compte 
FROM shop_commande 
AS sc, shop_commande_ligne AS scl, selectline_ref AS sl_ref 
WHERE sc.id = scl.shop_commande_id 
AND sl_ref.refshop = ISNULL(scl.shop_article_id, 0) 
AND sc.id NOT IN (SELECT id_command FROM selectline_flag)
```

Sometimes, in *sl_shop_article_id*, there is a NULL value. What I want is to replace it by 0 so the clause:

```
sl_ref.refshop = scl.shop_article_id
```

can work even if *scl.shop_article_id* is NULL. To do that I tried to use the ISNULL function but it makes the request wrong and I get there error:

*1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'*

How can I use it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are trying to use the `IFNULL()` function. IF you replaced `ISNULL` with `IFNULL` that should fix your query.

I suggest you go one step further and use `COALESCE()` instead of `IFNULL()`, since `COALESCE()` is part of the SQL standard (and `IFNULL()` is not).

```
SELECT sc.no, scl.quantite, scl.description, scl.poids, 
scl.prix, sl_ref.refsl, sl_ref.codetva, sl_ref.tauxtva, sl_ref.compte 
FROM shop_commande 
AS sc, shop_commande_ligne AS scl, selectline_ref AS sl_ref 
WHERE sc.id = scl.shop_commande_id 
AND sl_ref.refshop = COALESCE(scl.shop_article_id, 0) 
AND sc.id NOT IN (SELECT id_command FROM selectline_flag)
```

Comment: Work really fine, and didn't now about COALESCE, so thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    sc.no
    , scl.quantite
    , scl.description
    , scl.poids
    , scl.prix
    , sl_ref.refsl
    , sl_ref.codetva
    , sl_ref.tauxtva
    , sl_ref.compte 
FROM shop_commande 
AS sc, shop_commande_ligne AS scl, selectline_ref AS sl_ref 
WHERE sc.id = scl.shop_commande_id 
AND sl_ref.refshop = IFNULL(scl.shop_article_id, 0) 
AND sc.id NOT IN (SELECT id_command FROM selectline_flag)
```

Comment: You can see difference between `ISNULL()` and `IFNULL()` functions here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp

Comment: Thanks for the link and the quick answer ! As Ike said COALESCE is a part of the SQL standard, I'll use his answer, but yours work fine too !