# ISNULL if one or two columns are blank then 0

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement something like this

```
ISNULL(revenue - expense, 0)
```

I'm trying to find if one or both of my columns (revenue AND/OR expense) are blank. If either or both are blank then return 0. I keep getting #Error messages as a result though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ISNULL(value, 0) in WHERE clause MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932426/isnullvalue-0-in-where-clause-mysql)

Comment: Please see: [Why should I accept an answer when my query is resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 1):

Your statement suggests:

```
COALESCE(revenue - expense, 0)
```

However, logic dictates that you might really want:

```
COALESCE(revenue, 0) - COALESCE(expense, 0)
```

That is, treat each one individually as `0` if the value is `NULL`.

Note that number values are not really "blank" (which implies an empty string).  They are `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`COALESCE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(revenue - expense, 0)
FROM tab_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce), you can also use [`IfNull()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function **in MySQL**:

```
SELECT IFNULL(revenue - expense, 0) 
FROM your_table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use coalesce  function below way

```
     Select  Coalesce(revnue,0)-coalesce(expense,0)  
     from t
```