# How to set NULL to another value when exporting SQL databases with many columns?

Tags: mysql, json, export, mariadb, sql-null

I have a SQL database with approx. 200 columns that I want to export to `json` which is similar to this:

```
id  ab1  cd2  ef3  ...
 1    1    0 NULL   
 2    0    1    1
 3 NULL    0 NULL
 4   -9 NULL NULL
....
```

Normally, I'm happy with MySQL Workbench's **export wizard** which does this to select:

```
SELECT ab1,cd2,ef3,... FROM myDatabase
```

However, when I export to `json` the normal way, the difference between `0` and `NULL` is lost, because both the `NULL` values and the `0` values appear as `0` in the `json`. So I bit the sour apple and followed [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7930827/6574038) to face my problem like so:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(id,-9) AS id,
  COALESCE(ab1,-9) AS ab1,  
  COALESCE(cd2,-9) AS cd2,                        
  COALESCE(ef3,-9) AS ef3,
  ...
FROM myDatabase
```

But the **export wizard** throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\workbench\
        wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 192, in thread_work
self.func()
File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\
      sqlide_power_export_wizard.py", line 264, in start_export
retval = self.module.start(self.stop)
File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\
      sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 273, in start
ret = self.start_export()
File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules\
      sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 601, in start_export
rset = self._editor.executeManagementQuery(query, 1)
DBError: ("You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
           to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
          'id,-9) AS id, COALESCE(ab1,-9) AS ab1, COALESCE(cd2,-9) AS cd2, COALESCE(ef3,-9)' 
          at line 1", 1064)
ERROR: Export data to file: ("You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
                             manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
                             for the right syntax to use near 'id,-9) AS id, 
                             COALESCE(ab1,-9) AS ab1, COALESCE(cd2,-9) AS cd2, COALESCE(ef3,-9)' 
                             at line 1", 1064)
Failed
```

I don't know if it's just a syntax error or something else. I already tried just `id` instead of `COALESCE(id,-9) AS ab1,` since it's the unique identifier but it didn't work. Affected are integer columns.

It seems reasonable to me that NULL is the default value, but I'm depending on the differentiation mentioned. (I hope the issue has nothing to do with the fact that I am shamefully using `MariaDB` with `MySQLWorkbench`.)

**How could I change `NULL` to another value as `-9` or `NA` when exporting my SQL database with 200 columns to `json`?**

#### *Edit:*

> There is [another
>   question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42932426/6574038) that reads
>   similar, but it is actually different, because the answer is
>   regarding a very special case with a `WHERE` clause. However I have no 
>   `WHERE` clause at all in my code, I want a simple general solution
>   for **all** columns without a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Could it be as simple as needing to enclose the `-9` in quotes? ie: `'-9'`

Comment: @Dave Not its the wrong function :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your suggestion. Since it didn't help me I've edited my question to differentiate it from the dupe.

Comment: @Dave Didn't work, thanks though.

Comment: It will work for the SELECT columns just as well as on a WHERE clause

Comment: A table with 200 columns sounds like a bit of a design error, but who knows

Comment: I'm sorry @RiggsFolly, in the question I show how I tried to adapt your suggestion for the `WHERE` clause to my simpler case, but it won't work. If you don't mind, show me how it works.

Comment: You do realise you are using that same alias for the first 2 coalesce commands  `COALESCE(id,-9) AS ab1,
  COALESCE(ab1,-9) AS ab1,` Is that your problem

Comment: Oh, thanks, fixed! That was just carelessness, it' correct in my real code though.